# How to delete a single value within a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, unique, na

I would like to delete a single value of a cell within a data.frame. The value is a factor (numeric)

I tried to access the value like this:

```
which(colnames(df) == "variable.name")
which(rownames(df) == "row.name")

df[i, j] <- NULL
```

I was also trying to produca a NA by <- is.na, this didn't work as well. How would I do this?

Comment: If you know the indices of your value, try `df[row,column] <- NA`. If you know the value, try `df[df == value] <- NA`.

Comment: That worked, thx. And how can I get the cell emtpy?

Comment: `df[i,j]<-""` will empty the cell

Comment: @Metrics - it depends what the OP means by "empty."  if you set the cell to `''` the cell exists with a single `character` element. In fact, `'' < 0` returns `TRUE` . Much safer to use `NA` in my opinion.  In fact, since a `dataframe` or `matrix` requires equal -length rows and columns, you cannot have a truly "empty" cell (i.e. of length zero)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are significant differences between NULL and NA.

`NULL` is an *object*, typically used to mean the variable contains no object.

`NA` is a *value* that typically means "missing data item here".

In the main, a data frame is a list of equal length vectors. While an R list is an object that can contain other objects, an R vector is an object that can only contain values. Consequently, you can have a list of NULLs, but you cannot have a vector of NULLs.

In your example, you are trying to put a NULL object into a vector object (`df$j` or `df[,j]` or `df[[j]]`), which is part of a data frame. As a vector object cannot contain other objects (only values) the assignment failed.

As noted in the comments, `df[i, j] <- NA` will put an NA value in the data frame at the desired location. This is probably the best way to indicate emptyness.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing your code. I tried it but I got some errors.
I tried this to change cell value from "None" to NA then I converted the variable to numeric:

```
levels(data$Impact.Factor)
which(colnames(data) == "Impact.Factor")
#which(rownames(data) =="None" )--> did not work
which(grepl("None", data$Impact.Factor))
#df[row,column] <- NA
data[ 203,12] <- NA
data$Impact.Factor<-as.numeric(data$Impact.Factor)
```

Comment: Hi Mohammed, do not use the answer function to ask a related question. Better post a separate question with a reproducible example and delete this one.
Try this:  `as.character(data$Impact.Factor)`. Then replace the  `"None"` 's with `NA_character_` and try to change the variable to numeric. If you read the data into r using the argument stringsAsFactors = FALSE you avoid character variables to become factors. I guess that would be preferable in your case.